# Setting `this.[variable value]` in ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I use the value of a variable to set a property of a class in ES2015?

Consider this code:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "";
    this.url = "";
  }

  //Set the options for class
  setOptions(options) {
    for (option in options) {
      this.option = options[option]; //Option 1
      this[option] = options[option]; //Option 2
    }
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.setOptions({name: 'Test', url: 'www.stackoverflow.com'});
```

I know that Option 1 isn't supposed to work, but seeing as though Option 2 also doesn't work, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to set class attributes programmatically.

Just to make it absolutely clear, I want to set 'name' and 'url' in the class, not a property called option.

Comment: Once you fix your variable declaration of `option`, it works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/popyL5dq/ Why do you think it doesn't work? What output are you getting?

Comment: *Doesn't work* Doesn't work how? Look at the console. You are likely to see a `ReferenceError` on the variable `option`. That should give you all the clues you need to track down the mistake.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES2015. It's basic JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the `for...in` syntax. `option` is not defined, you'll have to use `for(var option in options)` or `for(let option in options)`

When logging `test` after that, using option 2, the output is:

`Test {name: "Test", url: "www.stackoverflow.com"}`

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "";
    this.url = "";
  }

  //Set the options for class
  setOptions(options) {
    for (let option in options) {
      this[option] = options[option]; //Option 2
    }
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.setOptions({name: 'Test', url: 'www.stackoverflow.com'});

console.log(test);
```

As suggested by jfriend00 you can also simply use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "";
    this.url = "";
  }

  //Set the options for class
  setOptions(options) {
    Object.assign(this, options);
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.setOptions({name: 'Test', url: 'www.stackoverflow.com'});

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Unbelievable.. I have this fixed in my actual code, but didn't think it would be a big deal because it would just be a 'global' JS variable, so didn't retest after adding it in.. I'll select yours as the best answer once stackoverflow lets me

Comment: Or maybe just use `Object.assign()` and let it copy all the properties over.

Comment: +1 for `Object.assign`, but be aware that this could do nasty things if you have any other named properties on your object and an object gets passed in with any of the same property names.

Answer (score -1):

ES6 classes are in strict mode even without `"use strict"`.

Strict mode forbids implicit globals.

`option` variable is not declared anywhere.

Thus, attempting to assign some value to it will throw a `ReferenceError`.